# Difference between DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName and DOMXPath::query?

Tags: php, dom

DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName() and DOMXPath::query() both return a DOMNodeList. Yet, they seem to work differently:

```
// Works as expected, removes all scripts
$r=$doc->getElementsByTagName('script');
while($r->length){
    $el=$r->item(0);
    $el->parentNode->removeChild($el);
}

// Error
$r=$xpath->query('//comment()');
while($r->length){
    $el=$r->item(0);
    $el->parentNode->removeChild($el);
}

// Works as expected, removes all comments
$r=$xpath->query('//comment()');
foreach($r as $el){
    $el->parentNode->removeChild($el);

}
```

Why are they different? The DOMNodeList returned by `getElementsByTagName()` automatically shifts the indexes down when the first node is removed while the DOMNodeList returned by `query()` simply makes the first index null. Are there other differences?

Comment: I think the issue is whether the node list in `$r` is "live": does it get updated automatically when the DOM is modified? Looks like `DOMDocument` returns a live node list, `DOMXPath` doesn't.

Comment: PHP's XML implementation is faulty. I am facing so many problems.

Comment: I also noticed that traversing with `query` seems to make more sense than traversing a list generated by the other functions; the order of the node list is different with the two